Match Index breaks when slicer is applied to lookup array
TL:DR I have a lot going on in this workbook, but it seems to boil down to an issue with a slicer affecting the way a match index is looking up values and breaking in part, but not in whole. In other words it works for some rows but not others when a slicer selection is made.
I've got a workbook that uses 3 data sources to compile a quality rate for 2 different processes. Sheets include Process 1(inbound), Process 2(outbound), and Comprehensive Defects(exception).
workbook output/dashboard with no slicers active
In trying to visualize this data I've got many helper columns on each sheet, due in part to the way the data is exported and in part to build references between the sheets.
I'm using Slicers on a table of dynamic arrays to make the end product ready for the lowest users for selection of dates and other attributes to drill down the data. The slicers have a helper column called "selection" on the exception sheet with a boolean value that I am trying to reference in the other 2 sheets (also "selection") with a match index, and I am successful... in part.
exception sheet has a helper to see a slicer selection =AGGREGATE(3,5,[@Date])
inbound and outbound have a helper to reference that column
=INDEX(Exception_Table[selection],MATCH([@Date],Exception_Table[Date],0))
My problem is that when I apply at least 1 slicer, this match index in the inbound and outbound sheets doesn't find every match. it returns partial or maybe wrong results. I did get it to work with MAXIFS, but that is much slower and the dataset is going to grow so I would like to get this match index working or another alternative. I am likely going to be working with a peer to migrate this to PowerBI eventually, but need a solution for the interim.
no slicers with sum of pick_line highlighted
pick_line slicer added with lower sum than expected
outbound sheet with 0 in 10/21/2024 match index where should have 1
exception sheet showing 10/21/2024 rows with value of 1
Thank you in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What's the formula in selection helper column in the exception table? If it is =AGGREGATE(3,5,[@date]) * AGGREGATE(3,5,[Order type])... to reflect all slicer choices, there could be hidden values in cells above with value 0 for Order type <> pick_line but for the same date. Matching as written does not exclude those.

@nkalvi the formula is =AGGREGATE(3,5,[@Date])

@JamesMontoya, right, but the column could have 0s above based on Order Type selection. I'm not sure about the result you're looking for - this would get your the first match among the visible rows: =INDEX(Exception_Table[selection],MATCH(1,Exception_Table[selection] * ([@Date] = Exception_Table[Date]),0)) it is basically "get the first match among the visible rows for the selected data".

Thank you! That did it. I see what you're saying about the hidden rows. @nkalvi

You're most welcome @JamesMontoya!
